# Chrome inspect android emulator does not work

Tags: android, emulation, inspect

I'm trying inspect my web view app in android emulator. Chrome lists the app in chrome://inspect but it doesn't shows nothing when I press the Inspect link. Inspector does not work with any app o browser, Inspector works fine in my real device.

I'm Mac user. The emulator debug settings is on.
Any idea??
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you open the debug in your code?

```
webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Hi alei, thanks for your answer. My project is an Ionic app, and Chrome inspector works well in my real device. The problem is only in the emulator.